# Hreflangs and canonicals. Should I chose the canonical version of the page for hreflang tags?

Tags: canonical-url, hreflang, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

So, basically we have implemented canonical tag, which points to the url with the parameters stripped. For instance, if somebody visits the page

https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php?someparameter=value

The value of the canonical tag on this page would be:

```
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php" rel="canonical" />
```

Now, how should we go about hreflang tag in this case?

Should it point to the canonical language versions of the page like that?

```
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/some-page.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" />
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" />
```

or should it use the exact url accessed by the user?

```
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/some-page.php?someparameter=value" rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" />
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php?someparameter=value" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" />
```

Which is the right scenario? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If parameter is not affecting content than you need to specify passive typed parameter in [URL Parameters tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en) and use your first solution:

```
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/some-page.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" />
<link href="https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" />
```

In that case you don't need to specify canonical:

<strike>`<link href="https://mywebsite.com/en/some-page.php" rel="canonical" />`</strike>

Note: Consider of using active parameter type in case it actually affects page content